# Return HTTP status code 201 in flask

Tags: python, flask, httpresponse

We're using Flask for one of our API's and I was just wondering if anyone knew how to return a HTTP response 201?

For errors such as 404 we can call:

```
from flask import abort
abort(404)
```

But for 201 I get

> LookupError: no exception for 201

Do I need to create my own exception like [this](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/exceptions/#custom-errors) in the docs?

Comment: `return '', 201`

Comment: This, as 201 is not an error. It is a success status.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can read about it [here.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#about-responses)

```
return render_template('page.html'), 201
```

Comment: This requires `page.html`... It won't work by itself.

Comment: For me this type of error handling worked (behind IIS) only if InvalidUsage was a child of werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException, not a general Exception

Answer (score 250):

You can use Response to return any http status code.

```
> from flask import Response
> return Response("{'a':'b'}", status=201, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: You can rewrite this as `return {'a':'b'}, 201, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`, or simply as `return {'a': 'b'}, 201`

Comment: @MasoodKhaari's approach is actually correct since it returns valid JSON - it looks like `{'a':'b'}` gets automatically converted to `{"a":"b"}`. The double quotes are correct JSON. The original answer actually returns single quotes.

Answer (score 50):

You can do

```
result = {'a': 'b'}
return result, 201
```

if you want to return a JSON data in the response along with the error code
You can read about responses [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses) and [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response) for make_response API details

Answer (score 32):

As lacks suggested send status code in return statement
and if you are storing it in some variable like

```
notfound = 404
invalid = 403
ok = 200
```

and using

```
return xyz, notfound
```

than time make sure its type is int not str. as I faced this small issue
also here is list of status code followed globally 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good way, but better to access them as a module like `status.NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 15):

In your flask code, you should ideally specify the MIME type as often as possible, as well:

```
return html_page_str, 200, {'ContentType':'text/html'}

return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

...etc

Answer (score 11):

Ripping off [Luc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201863/luc) [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824101/return-http-status-code-201-in-flask#comment61849860_7824101), but to return a blank response, like a `201` the simplest option is to use the following return in your route.

```
return "", 201
```

So for example:

```py
    @app.route('/database', methods=["PUT"])
    def database():
        update_database(request)
        return "", 201
```

Answer (score 7):

you can also use flask_api for sending response

```
from flask_api import status

@app.route('/your-api/')
def empty_view(self):
    content = {'your content here'}
    return content, status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

you can find reference here http://www.flaskapi.org/api-guide/status-codes/

Comment: upvoted for using a constant instead of a magic number

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to combine the above in order to make it work

```
return Response(json.dumps({'Error': 'Error in payload'}), 
status=422, 
mimetype="application/json")
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependent on how the API is created, normally with a 201 (created) you would return the resource which was created. For example if it was creating a user account you would do something like:

```
return {"data": {"username": "test","id":"fdsf345"}}, 201
```

Note the postfixed number is the status code returned.

Alternatively, you may want to send a message to the client such as:

```
return {"msg": "Created Successfully"}, 201
```

Answer (score 2):

for error 404 you can

```
def post():
    #either pass or get error 
    post = Model.query.get_or_404()
    return jsonify(post.to_json())
```

for 201 success

```
def new_post():
    post = Model.from_json(request.json)
    return jsonify(post.to_json()), 201, \
      {'Location': url_for('api.get_post', id=post.id, _external=True)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add your status code after your returning data like this:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():  # put application's code here
    return 'Hello World!',201
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It's a basic flask project. After starting it and you will find that when we request `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` you will get a status 201 from web broswer console.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a ten year old question that has been answered already! :o)

Answer (score 1):

So, if you are using **`flask_restful`** Package for API's
returning 201 would becomes like

```
def bla(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return data, 201
```

where `data` should be any hashable/ JsonSerialiable value, like dict, string.