# How to send a status 200 answering to a HTTPS POST in python

Tags: python, https, http-status-code-200

I am using Flask to create an application that receives some data from a server with an HTTPS POST and process its data. Once i receive the message from the server I need to send a "status = 200" so the server will know that i got the info, and stop re-sending me the information.

Do i have to send a HTTPS GET? It is not really a get as the only thing i need is to notify the server i got the message...

How can i do it in python? I need to do it after processing the data i receive but without return.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])``
def webhook():


req = request.form
xml = req['data']
#HOW DO I SEND A CODE 200 NOW???
info = ET.fromstring(xml)
print info[0].text
print info[1].text
print info[2].text
print info[3].text
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your route, can't you just `return ''` - that'll be an empty response with a status of 200 I believe.

Comment: Yes, but i was wondering if  there was a "more professional" way to do it xD

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be sure about the response code, you can send an empty response and only specify the response code like so

```
return '', 200
```

The complete answer can be found at [Return HTTP status code 201 in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824101/return-http-status-code-201-in-flask)

**UPDATE FOR UPDATED QUESTION:**

You could use a `Thread` for that.

```
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])``

def worker(xml):
  info = ET.fromstring(xml)

  print info[0].text
  print info[1].text
  print info[2].text
  print info[3].text

  return

def webhook():
  req = request.form
  xml = req['data']

  # This executes in background
  t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(xml,))
  t.start()

  # So that you can return before worker is done
  return '', 200
```

Comment: The thing is that actually I need to return something once i have process the data. 

Can i send the status 200 just after reciving the data in the middle of the code? I have just update the question to show it

Comment: @Alex once you return a response - that's it... (unless you're passing off to a worker process/thread/whatever) However, we're now approaching a completely new question. "How do I return a 200 response" has been answered.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But do you have any ideas about how to solve the new question?