# Make flask return status-code that is not just a number for Vertex AI

Tags: python, flask

In the Vertex AI [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements) it is stated "...request within 10 seconds with status code `200 OK`. The contents of the response body do not matter;".

I have never used Flask before (I have used Django) but a lot of exampels on how to make a custom container is with flask. I struggle to figure out how I can return `200 OK` as **status code** (I find that phrasing odd, since I have never seen status-codes being anything else than a number)

I have tried this

```py
from flask import Flask,Response,make_response
.
.

@app.route('/health',methods=["GET","POST"])
def health():
    return Response("OK",status=200)


@app.route('/health',methods=["GET","POST"])
def health():
    return Response(status="200 OK")


@app.route('/health',methods=["GET","POST"])
def health():
    return make_response("200 OK")
```

but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Flask [docs on response object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/) mention that you have either `status` or `status_code` available.

```
property status: str
    The HTTP status code as a string.

property status_code: int
    The HTTP status code as a number.
```

This would imply that you could just use status_code in your example.
Alternatively you could use a return without the response object, like so:

```
result = {'a': 'b'}
return result, 200
```

As taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824101/return-http-status-code-201-in-flask) semi related to yours.

Comment: My question is that in their docs it's written as the *status code* has to be `200 OK` and not just `200` (which implies OK).

Comment: That might be a language thingy vs being explicit in a technical document, since it also states to return "503 Service Unavailable", which you can imagine is also not a valid integer. It is however a valid status code as it confirms to the standard list. The OK in this case is implied after a 200 but technically up to the receiver to interpret. Bottom line, when asked for a HTTP status code, always assume just the number.